# Swift Sprite-Kit: How do I increase my game's score when screen is touched?

Tags: ios, swift, touch, sprite-kit

In my game, every touch moves the background down 50 pixels, I want every touch during a certain animation to translate into a score of 50. In my code, I have two background nodes that make my background scroll down with every touch without a gap in the background.  I have a problem updating the score when the green light animation runs, and make the game end when the screen is touched during a red light animation.  I have already created a score label.  Thank you in advance.

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if bg.position.y + bg.size.height/2 < 50
    {
        let diff =  bg.position.y + bg.size.height/2 - 50
        bg.position.y = self.frame.height + bg.size.height/2 + diff
    }
    else
    {
        bg.position.y -= 50
    }
    if bg2.position.y + bg2.size.height/2 < 50
    {
        let diff =  bg2.position.y + bg2.size.height/2 - 50
        bg2.position.y = self.frame.height + bg2.size.height/2 + diff
    }
    else
    {
        bg2.position.y -= 50
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have both green lights and red lights place one on top of the other? and `animateGreenLight` shows both colors already. then why do you have another `animateRedLight` action?

Comment: Yes you're right, the red light animation was unnecessary. I only kept one animation in the general name of "light".  And the reason they are in the same position, is because I want them to switch between the two.

Comment: How would you set up a bool like @Nfinity recommended for the redLight and the greenLight, and when they are showing, when it is at random time intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var currentLight : SKSpriteNode!
    var greenTexture : SKTexture!
    var redTexture : SKTexture!
    var isGreenLightON : Bool = true
    var score : Int = 0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        greenTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "green light.png")
        redTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "red light.png")

        currentLight = SKSpriteNode(texture: greenTexture)
        currentLight.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 650)


        let changeToGreenLight : SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in
            self.currentLight.texture =  self.greenTexture
            self.isGreenLightON = true
        })

        let changeToRedLight : SKAction = SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in
            self.currentLight.texture = self.redTexture
            self.isGreenLightON = false
        })

        let changingLights = SKAction.sequence([changeToGreenLight,SKAction.waitForDuration(1, withRange: 4),changeToRedLight,SKAction.waitForDuration(1, withRange: 4)])

        currentLight.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(changingLights))

        self.addChild(currentLight)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if isGreenLightON
        {
            score += 50
        }
        else
        {
            score -= 10
        }
        println(score)

        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    }



    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
       // Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: the animation for the light is not set at a random time, how do I fix that.

Comment: updated my code. changed repeated action to   `let changingLights = SKAction.sequence([changeToGreenLight,SKAction.waitForDuration(1, withRange: 4),changeToRedLight,SKAction.waitForDuration(1, withRange: 4)])`

Comment: Also, I have a scoreLabel node, how do I update the scoreLabel on the gamescene to the actual score.

Comment: `scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"` in `touches began`. check code.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Last question, how do I make the game end when the screen is touched when the red light is up.

Comment: do I change to "else { gameOver scene}. what is the code for that

Comment: that you have to decide.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a bool for greenLightIsShowing and redLightIsShowing and set them to true and false depending on when they are showing. Then just handle the touches when the bools are true.

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {   

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if greenLightIsShowing == true {

            if nodeAtPoint(location) == self.view {

            score = score + 50
            scoreLable.text = "\(score)"

        }
}else if redLightIsShowing == true {
          if nodeAtPoint(location) == self.view {
            //end the game
        }
}
```